# Finding discrete rth roots

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is finding the integer $r^{th}$ root of an integer (if it exists) polynomial time? What is the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The algorithm is: take logarithms to sufficient accuracy, divide by $r$, exponentiate to sufficient accuracy, round off to the nearest integer, and check whether the $r$th power of that integer is the original number.